# Spring boot with i18n (internationalization) and thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, thymeleaf

I am trying to get i18n to work with my spring boot application, which uses thymeleaf as template engine.

I followed some tutorials, which showed me how to define message source and locale resolver, so I made this configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource msgSrc = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        msgSrc.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        msgSrc.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return msgSrc;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        resolver.setCookieName("myI18N_cookie");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry reg) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("locale");
        reg.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }

}
```

Then, in my resource folder (src/main/resources) i made folder **i18n** and inside i put **messages.properties** and **messages_sl.properties**

inside there is defined **first.greeting = Hello World!**

And this is my thymeleaf template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:with="lang=${#locale.language}" th:lang="${lang}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/?locale=en">English</a> | <a href="/?locale=sl">Slovenian</a>
        <h3 th:text="#{first.greeting}"></h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Controller is nothing special, it just forwards this view when I access it and in my properties file i have defined:

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

However, when I load page, instead of **Hello World!** I get **??first.greeting_en??** or **??first.greeting_sl??**, depending on set locale.

Everywhere I looked I saw same configuration, so I am really lost as what am I missing.

And here is my project structure:

```
 src
   └───  main
       ├───  java
       │   └───  com
       │       └───  mjamsek
       │           └───  Simple_i18n
       │               ├───  conf
       │               └───  controller
       └───  resources
           ├───  i18n
           │   ├─── messages.properties
           │   └─── messages_sl.properties
           ├───  static
           └───  templates
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the `classpath:` prefix to `MessageSource's` basename

```
msgSrc.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
```